# How to use the views of angular2 for the backend work done in zf2 (routing the view using #)

Tags: angular, zend-framework2, angular2-routing

I want to use Angular 2 as front end and Zend framework 2 as backend for a project. How can i connect the view of angular 2 to zend framework 2.

Comment: i am practicing Student Application. Wrote Controller and Model that can retrieve data from database and want that data to view using angular2. The controllers returns json data, how can i use data in angular2.?

Comment: Again, what have you tried to use that Json data from your controller. Did you read AngularJs tutorials ? Did you tried something into your view with angular ?

Comment: Yeah i read Angular2 Typescript tutorial. I just followed the hero example, wrote services, components, routes, modules and every thing. Angular2 is working perfectly, i just doesn't understand how to access data that returned by controller.

Comment: google it once and found : https://github.com/hantsy/angularjs-zf2-sample

Comment: Read the wiki of this skeleton : https://github.com/hantsy/angularjs-zf2-sample/wiki

Comment: i already checked that. it was in angular 1 that too js, and i am doing in typescript, there is so much difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular2 is quite different from AngularJS indeed.

But you can communicate with PHP as long as you consider your zf2 as an app for angular2 side.

Your zend framework controller has just to return JsonData. As you already done this part, you just have to configure angular2 to take knowledge of your zf2 app :

[this link](http://4dev.tech/2016/07/using-http-client-to-integrate-angular2-to-php/) could be explain everything to make this work.

> Your may adapt this code from the link

It says you have to import some variables (use your own config here) :

> We’re going to need Http Client to be able to send requests to our
>   server, in order to use it on our project we have to register it as a
>   service provider on our main.ts:

```
import { bootstrap }    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
bootstrap(AppComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS]);
```

and this in your (`app.component.ts`) :

```
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import {Injectable, Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<ul>
        <li *ngFor="let person of data">
           {{person.id}} - {{person.first_name}}
        </li>
         </ul>`
})
export class AppComponent { 

    private data;

    constructor(private http:Http){
    }

    ngOnInit(){
        this.getData();
    }

    getData(){
        this.http.get('http://{your host}/{your project}/')
                .subscribe(res => this.data = res.json());
    }
}
```

the author explain all of his code on the link above but i pasted it here for perennity of this answer :

> Most of what’s in this code probably isn’t new for you, so I won’t
>   bother to explain all the basic things again. What matters here is the
>   getData() method, that’s where we’re getting the data from that php
>   web service we created at the beginning.
>
> Now let’s see how it actually works, if you take a look at the code
>   you’ll see that I’ve used two functions to be able to get the data:
>   get() and subscribe(). The first receives the web service url and
>   calls the server to get the data, while the second one specifies the
>   actions that should be taken when it receives the response, in this
>   case I’m just assigning the received data to the this.data variable,
>   pretty simple right?